# Control Docker from an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, docker, asp.net-core

Is it possible to control Docker using ASP.NET Core MVC?

I've recently wrote a simple app wich send exact commands to opened cmd process (on Windows OS). I know that it is not the best solution to achieve what I want, because I need to open new process and also give it an root privileges. I want to know if there is a possible way to controll docker container that run some application on it using some kinds of endpoints? Or maybe there is a better way to do such things?

Comment: So you're looking for a Docker API to call from a web application. Not control another application

Comment: What's preventing you from doing what you want? Did you break your work down into small tasks and then try to accomplish those tasks?

Comment: Hi. In my opinion calling an cmd.exe with root priviliges alongside main app isn't the best soultion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker does have an HTTP API that can be called from other applications, including web apps. You can find the documentation in the [Docker Engine API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/) site. You can call the API using curl or HttpClient.

There's also a [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) that hides the implementation details.

Copying from the examples, once you install the NuGet package you can list containers with:

```
using Docker.DotNet;
DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(
    new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine"))
     .CreateClient();

IList<ContainerListResponse> containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(
    new ContainersListParameters(){
        Limit = 10,
    });
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer. Can my docker also send me back some info? For example I send using this api string -> "10+10" it calculate it on its own inside and then I received from it score in int -> 20 which could be again used inside app.